# Using arcpy dictionaries to select attributes from a different layer

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, dictionary

I'd like to incorporate the use of dictionaries to access data between tables. So far I have been able to create the dictionaries that I need from my feature class fields.  I have one dictionary that lists multiple Property values for one key `[(u'1010305', [u'1014414', u'1014395', u'1014381']), (u'1010306', [u'1014396', u'1014415', u'1014432', u'1014414', u'1014395', u'1014382', u'1014381'])...`. I would like to use the values associated to each key to select rows ("select by attribute") in another table.  While I can call the values by key or item in the command window I can't seem to incorporate them into a SelectLayerByAttribute function.  This is the code so far :

```
# Purpose: Create a dictionary of values that combines Recipient Claims to Allocating Claims from the BufferRecipientClaims feature class.
# Usage: No arguments needed.
# Source : Python for ArcGIS, Laura Tateosian, 2015, Springer, Chapter 18 p.349.

import arcpy, numpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "CURRENT"
fc = "RecipientBufferClaims"

# Populate the dictionary,
# accumulate a list of Recipient Claims (Value) for each Allocation Claim (Key) type.
dict = {}
SearchCurs = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("RecipientBufferClaims",["RecClmNum","AllocClmNum"])
for row in SearchCurs:
    Recipient = row[0]
    Allocation = row[1]
    if dict.has_key(Recipient):
        dict[Recipient].append(Allocation)
    else:
        dict[Recipient] = [Allocation]
del SearchCurs
```

All of which works.  I'd like to use something like the following to select rows in a new table using the returned values for the key "1010305" but I'm getting an error message

```
for k, v in dict.values["1010305"]:
    AllocationVariable = AllocationVariable(v)
    print "the allocation claim numbers are  {0} ".format(AllocationVariable)
    arcpy.selectLayerByAttribute(fc,""" "AllocClmNum" = AllocationVariable """)

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Edit: I did manage to get this to update another table, unfortunately it did so without filtering the values associated to the key 1010305, but I'm getting closer (code below).

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("ActualTbleCopy2SortedAllocationClaims",["AllocClmNum","CorrAllocCreVal"]) as UpdateCurs:
    for row in UpdateCurs:
        for k, v in dict.items():
            RecipientNumber = str(k)
            if RecipientNumber == ("1010305"):
                row[1] = 9999
                UpdateCurs.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Where  are the k v values in your for loop ?

Comment: As I understand it the k and v values refer to my Key and Value elements in my dictionary : "AllocClmNum","CorrAllocCreVal" in the first set of code.

Comment: If you get the 'too many values to unpack' error, you need to enclose your k,v variables in brackets so they are treated as a tuple: for (k, v) in ...

Comment: Also, 'dict' is a reserved word, so is not a good variable name. Try calling it myDict or something else.

Comment: @jon_two. Thanks for your suggestions.  I'll change my 'dict' variable  and keep your solution for the 'too many values to unpack' in mind as I progress.  Excellent points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a few things:

1. when you store your multiple values for each key make sure it a tuple and not a list
2. After you correctly stored your key value(tuple) pairs in your dictionary. Try calling the dictionary like this

   ```
   for k,v in dict.items():
       if k = "1010305":
           qry = "AllocClmNum IN {}".format(v)
           arcpy.selectLayerByAttribute(fc, qry)
   ```

EDIT: saving you v values to a variable

```
for k,v in dict.items():
        if k = "1010305":
            values = tuple(v)
            qry = "AllocClmNum IN {}".format(values)
            arcpy.selectLayerByAttribute(fc, qry)
```

to index you would just do something like this:

```
ex: print values[1]
    print values[3] etc...
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems like the solution I am looking for.  But I'm not clear on how I change my multiple values for each keys into a tuple rather than a list.  Something like : tupleValues = (row[0],row[1])?

Comment: You just want the values stored in the tuple - not the key

Comment: dict[Recipient] = (Allocation)

Comment: what does your dictionary look like when you print it out? maybe i am not understanding it correctly

Comment: Thanks again.  Using  your code suggestion above I get the following  printed dictionary result :`'AllocClmNum IN [u'1014414', u'1014395', u'1014381']` which is exactly what I want it to return : the values that are associated to the key value.  Can these values now be accessed by index?  I need to use these values to select rows from another table based on each of these values and then run another calculation.

Comment: if you save your v values to a variable, then you will be able to index them if they are a list or tuple

Comment: Very nice.  It all seems to be coming together.  Your example code works perfectly so far and you've helped me understand the logic behind these dictionaries.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Frederic accept my answer if it helped you